# Why does a Turing machine take n^k steps for computing an input?

Tags: turing-machines, turing-complete

I was reading about Cook's Theorem for Turing machine. In its proof, it is said that the Turing would take at most n^k steps (where k is an integer and k > 0) to compute an input of length 'n'

This is probably assuming that the Turing machine does halt for the given input
It further says that we as there are at most n^k steps, we don't need an infinite tape. A tape with n^k elements is sufficient as the turning machine would not travel more than that

Why do we say the Turing Machine needs atmost n^k steps?

Comment: this seems like a question more suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/, since there they discuss math theory, while here we discuss problems with code using said theory.

Comment: Thank you, I will post the question there :)